# Execute sql script when updating database schema Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to append (or execute) a custom sql queries when executing:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I have a script that create all my views and I want them to be updated whenever I update the database schema.

Comment: You can create custom console's commands on symfony : [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html).

Comment: Is there a way on how to extends the doctrine command?

Comment: look at this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#invoking-other-commands)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can extend the [`UpdateSchemaCommand`](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-commands-service-provider/blob/master/src/Dflydev/Pimple/Provider/DoctrineCommands/Command/Proxy/UpdateSchemaCommand.php) command and inject the `EntityManager` into by [defining the command as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/commands_as_services.html).

The command:

```
// src/AppBundle/Command/CustomUpdateSchemaCommand.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;

class CustomUpdateSchemaCommand extends UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Hello world');
        $conn = $this->em->getConnection();
        $conn->exec(/* QUERY */);


        return parent::execute($input, $output);
    }
}
```

The service:

```
// app/config/services.yml
app.command.custom_schema_update_command:
    class: App\SportBundle\Command\CustomUpdateSchemaCommand
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        -  { name: console.command }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you're welcome @MNIFAKRAM. Just in case, why you don't up-voted the answer? Do you think there is something that is not in the answer or could be better? Sometimes SO beginners just forgot to up vote.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget.